# mobile switching is not working in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-middleware

i have django project in which mobile part settings.py configured as  given below

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
                      'site_middleware.SetSiteFromHost',
                     )
SITE_ID = 1
```

and site_middleware.py :

```
class SetSiteFromHost:


    def process_request(self, request):
        if mobileBrowser(request):
            if request.GET.get('server', False):

                request.session['server_mode'] = True
                site = 1
            elif request.session.get('server_mode') == True:

                site = 1
            else:

                request.session['server_mode'] = False
                site = 2

        else:
            site = 1
        settings.SITE_ID = site
```

Errors are not showing, but switching is not working?

Comment: What is *enter code here* in config?

Answer (score 2):

From documentation: [Altering settings at runtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime).

You shouldn't alter settings in your applications at runtime.

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.DEBUG = True   # Don't do this!
```

The only place you should assign to settings is in a settings file.

I think the best way is make several settings-file:

File `base_settings.py`:

```
 ... all your settings for all sites ...
```

File `first_site_settings.py`:

```
from base_settings import *

SITE_ID = 1

... other settings for this site ...
```

File `second_site_settings.py`:

```
from base_settings import *

SITE_ID = 2

... other settings for this site ...
```

And run each site as a separate djano-process:

```
$ python mysite/manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.first_site_settings
$ python mysite/manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.second_site_settings
```

Comment: but again same issue existing.

Comment: @SatheeshAlathiyur, just posted my solution.

Comment: but it not possible i have single url with two different templates one for mobiles and another for running on the computers. two settings.py is not a valuable solution, i think to switch the site based on the middleware

Comment: @SatheeshAlathiyur, I think in your case should be limited to something like `request.mobile_browser = True` (or other vars), and using it in views, templates, etc. `SITE_ID` used for other purposes.